# unity gone, gnome took over

Tags: unity, gnome

I am running ubuntu 11.04.  Today I booted up my machine and logged in as usual but found gnome running instead of unity.  I saw a similar thread where someone suggested using

> unity -- reset

This gave the following errors:

```
paul@paul-ubuntu:/$ unity --reset
WARNING: Unity currently default profile, so switching to metacity while resetting the values
unity-panel-service: no process found
Backend     : gconf
Integration : true
Profile     : unity
Adding plugins
Initializing core options...done
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 1
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 1
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 1
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 1
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 1
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 1
Initializing bailer options...done
Initializing detection options...done
Initializing composite options...done
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: No valid GL extensions string found.
Compiz (bailer) - Info: Ensuring a shell for your session
paul@paul-ubuntu:/$ Cannot register the panel shell: there is already one running.
```

Comment: What do you mean "Gnome?" In 11.04, do you mean Ubuntu Classic? Or did you install Gnome 3 and gnome shell. You need Compiz to run Unity. Try opening Synaptic Package Manager and re-installing Compiz window and Compositing Manager.

Answer (score 2):

In the login screen there's a little gear icon next to your name.  Click on it, and in the popup menu that appears, select "Unity" as your session type.  Then enter your password to log in.